# How to remove background grid in Bar Chart?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

[image]

I need to remove the background grid from the bar chart. I am using iOS-charts in iOS app.

Comment: To understand why your question got closed take a moment to read [ask]

Answer (score 5):

This should remove them...

```
yAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

Comment: this isn't working for me...I can do it with xAxis but not y...it says barChartView has no member yAxis

Comment: @AndyLebowitz found solution?

Comment: No yAxis found .. this not exists

Comment: This should do the trick: 
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false